# Restricting the creation of lines for network creation in QGIS: start/end vertices must snap to existing vertices

Tags: qgis, vector, topology, network, constraint

My interest lies in network creation, however, knowing how to do that in general would be a plus. How is it possible to prevent a user from creating a line (line vector) without connecting it perfectly to nodes (point vector) on both ends?

This would save tremendous time in topology checks and corrections later. I know about using snapping, but it is sadly not fool proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The idea: use virtual fields

To restrict the creation of lines to lines with start- and end points snapped to existing vertices, create a virtual field (updated whenever you add a feature) that checks if start- and endpoint are on a line segment. Then you have two options:

1. Set "hard" restraints - adding an unconnected line is not possible. Only lines connected at start- and endpoint will be added.
2. No restraints for adding lines, but unconnected lines will be highlighted visually until you connect them - this gives you a visual control where there are unconnected lines left and allows for a more intuitive workflow.

### Virtual field: the principles

For both options, first create a virutal field (then it is updated every time you add a feature). This field tests if the start-point is connected to a line. Name the field as `start`, set field type to boolean. Repeat the same for the end-point, creating a virtual field `end`.

Use the following expression for the startpoint (at the beginning of line two replace `start_point` with `end_point` to create field `end`):

```
intersects( 
    start_point ($geometry),
    difference (collect ($geometry), $geometry)
)
```

### Option 1: Setting hard restraints using constraints

Go to `Layer Properties / Attributes Form` and select the virtual fields. For `Constraints`, set (again) the expression from above for start- and end field. Be sure to check the box `Enforce expression constraint`.

Now, you won't be able any more to add unconnected lines. Only fully connected lines will be accepted.

*Setting the constraints:*
[image]

*Unconnected ends: you can't add the feature, `OK` button is grayed out:*
[image]

[image]

### Option 2: Visual control of unconnected features

Style the lines differently based on the result of that field. Like this, you have a visual control where there are unconnected lines left and you can connect them.

Set the layer's style to `Rule-based` and add two rules, one for `"start" = true and "end" = true` (both points connected to the network: green), the other for `"start" = false or "end" = false` (one or both points **not** connected to the network: red).

Now, you can visually recognize which lines are connected and which ones are not. Connecting unconnected lines changes their visual style as you can see in this screencast:

*Red: unconnected lines; green: connected lines. If unconnected lines are connected, their style changes. That gives a visual control of where there are unconnected lines and helps you to intuitively complete the lines:*
[image]

---